# Revertir una animación en android studio con java pulsando por segunda vez dicha animación

Tags: java, android-studio, app

estoy construyendo la parte de reacciones y he implementado una animación la cual quiero que cuando se pulse una vez se ejecute la animación y cuando el usuario la vuelva a pulsar esta vuelva a su estado inicial o al frame 0.

Estoy usando android studio y como lenguaje java.
La animación proviene de Lottie files

Comment: Bienvenido, cual es el código?, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Estoy preguntando como podría hacerlo, no tengo ningún código.

Comment: Solo necesito que cuando pulse una vez la animación esta se ejecute y cuando lo haga por segunda vez esta vuelva a su estado inicial